# How to Pass Quotes "" in a shell argument to java with argument containing white spaces

Tags: java, bash, shell, csv, whitespace

I am currently trying to execute following command

```
./launch.sh -version 212 -file "/root/Desktop/local test/list.csv"
```

The `launch.sh` assigns the arguments to a variable MY_VARIABLE

When the value is assigned then the quotes around the file path is removed and `echo $MY_VARIABLE` gives following result:

```
./launch.sh -version 212 -file /root/Desktop/local test/list.csv
```

Now `launch.sh` calls for Java and gives `MY_VARIABLE` as argument

But Java splits the argument for the file and try to process `/root/Desktop/local` and end up with an error while it should be taking `/root/Desktop/local test/list.csv`.

How can I ignore the white spaces in the Java argument or keep the quotes while assigning the value to the variable to make sure that I give the correct arguments.

Comment: Try escaping the whitespace like `\ ` and try.

Comment: Escaping the white space with \ is not working in this case. The result is same.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add two escaped quotes ( \" ) like this:

```
"\"/root/Desktop/local test/list.csv\""
```

Answer (score 0):

There are somany ways you can implement this. add escape sequence as Steafan said.or you can store this strings into a text file and read those values to a string from file

Answer (score 0):

> How can I ignore the white spaces in the Java argument

```
  public class Arguments {
      public static void main(String[] args){ 

            String together = "";
            for(int i=0; i < args.length; i++){
                System.out.println( args[i] );
                together = together.concat(args[i]);
            }
            System.out.println(together);

            for(int i=0; i < args.length; i++){
                System.out.println( args[i] );
            }
        }  
}
```

modifying that code you can concatenate any number of arguments you want.  After that you can use `together` as a single variable